# SQL Server 2014 - returning rows with non-zero values after group-by

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

The data looks like this:

```
eqId    date_   close_       high        low          open_   volume    bid          ask       totRtn      _rowId
4   2008-01-02  20.660004   21.100098   20.660004   21.100006   3650    20.649994   21.600006   113.229729  1827
4   2008-01-03  22.979996   22.990005   20.710007   21.100006   13200   21.779999   22.990005   125.944735  1828
4   2008-01-04  22.960007   22.979996   22.000000   22.729996   5600    22.100006   22.960007   125.835183  1829
4   2008-01-07  22.509995   22.949997   22.500000   22.699997   19800   22.520004   22.839996   123.368836  1830
4   2008-01-08  22.389999   22.850006   22.389999   22.500000   8500    22.270004   22.759995   122.711183  1831
4   2008-01-09  22.369995   22.949997   22.369995   22.389999   2100    22.300003   22.500000   122.601548  1832
4   2008-01-10  22.550003   22.619995   22.369995   22.369995   3000    22.399994   22.610001   123.588105  1833
4   2008-01-11  22.710007   22.729996   22.550003   22.729996   1400    22.559998   22.750000   124.465027  1834
4   2008-01-14  22.539993   22.750000   22.470001   22.479996   5700    22.529999   22.699997   123.533244  1835
4   2008-01-15  23.028000   23.028000   22.589996   22.750000   9249    22.750000   23.080002   126.207827  1836
4   2008-01-16  22.919998   23.100006   22.660004   23.000000   10600   22.669998   23.080002   125.615908  1837
4   2008-01-17  22.660004   23.149994   22.660004   23.149994   7325    22.660004   22.919998   124.190979  1838
4   2008-01-18  22.770004   23.089996   22.669998   22.949997   9200    22.770004   22.919998   124.793848  1839
4   2008-01-22  22.279999   22.809998   22.250000   22.509995   8900    22.300003   22.669998   122.108314  1840
4   2008-01-23  22.279999   22.889999   22.270004   22.500000   3900    22.300003   22.759995   122.108314  1841
4   2008-01-24  22.669998   22.910004   22.519897   22.520004   11800   22.550003   22.949997   124.245752  1842
4   2008-01-25  22.770004   22.880005   22.570007   22.690002   6700    22.619995   22.820007   124.793848  1843
```

what I am trying to do is count the total number of dates where, for a given eqid, across a defined date range (using a where statement), the volume was zero.  So, if I provide 1 year as a date range and there were 4 days that the stock did not trade at all i want to have the eqid and zero_count displayed.

the script I tried is:

```
SELECT eqId
      ,date_
      ,volume
      ,count(nullif(volume,0)) as hasvol
  FROM [CRC].[dbo].[eqPrice]
  where date_>'2007-12-31' and date_ < '2012-01-01'
  group by eqid,date_,volume
  order by eqid
```

but I get this result:

```
eqId    date_   volume  hasvol
4   2008-01-02 00:00:00 3650    1
4   2008-01-03 00:00:00 13200   1
4   2008-01-04 00:00:00 5600    1
4   2008-01-07 00:00:00 19800   1
4   2008-01-08 00:00:00 8500    1
4   2008-01-09 00:00:00 2100    1
4   2008-01-10 00:00:00 3000    1
4   2008-01-11 00:00:00 1400    1
4   2008-01-14 00:00:00 5700    1
4   2008-01-15 00:00:00 9249    1
4   2008-01-16 00:00:00 10600   1
4   2008-01-17 00:00:00 7325    1
4   2008-01-18 00:00:00 9200    1
4   2008-01-22 00:00:00 8900    1
```

i don't seem to be able to figure out the syntax to get the total number of days, just a count (of 1) for each day .

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT: Moved OP's reply here**

I ran this:

```
SELECT top 10 eqId,
       date_,
       CASE WHEN SUM(COALESCE(volume, 0)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS hasvol
  FROM [CRC].[dbo].[eqPrice]
  WHERE date_ > '2007-12-31'
  AND date_ < '2012-01-01'
  GROUP BY eqid, date_
  ORDER BY eqid, date_
```

and got this:

```
eqId    date_          hasvol
4    2008-01-02 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-03 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-04 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-07 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-08 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-09 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-10 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-11 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-14 00:00:00    1
4    2008-01-15 00:00:00    1
```

So I am still not getting one single number for each eqid over the ENTIRE date range :-(

### EDIT 2

I thought I was good to go, but, what is missing are any of the instances where there are no zero days for the entire date range.  I need to have the DayCntWhereVolumeIsZero show up as 0 when there is a reported non-zero volume for each day in the range.  sorry for the back and forth . . .thanks again

Comment: Can you have multiple entries for the same `eqId`/`date_`? How do you determine that there was no trade?  Is it by a lack of a row for a given date?  Or is it because the value of `volume` is zero?  Or possibly both?

Comment: for each date there is one eqid and if it did not trade then the volume will be zero.  I am trying to classify eqid liquidity by referencing (in part by) inactive days.

Comment: Why do you do `nullif`?  Do you expect the `volume` column to contain nulls in some cases?

Comment: I may not be understanding what you are expecting.  Can you edit your post and show us what your desired query should return if it were to work correctly?  That will clear things up quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that the `eqId`, `date_` combination is unique, as you explained in the comments.

```
SELECT eqId,
       date_,
       volume,
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(volume, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS hasvol
  FROM [CRC].[dbo].[eqPrice]
  WHERE date_ > '2007-12-31'
  AND date_ < '2012-01-01'
  ORDER BY eqid, date_
```

If you can have duplicate entries of `eqId`, `date_`, then this is probably the query that will get you what you want (using `GROUP BY`, `SUM`):

```
SELECT eqId,
       date_,
       CASE WHEN SUM(COALESCE(volume, 0)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS hasvol
  FROM [CRC].[dbo].[eqPrice]
  WHERE date_ > '2007-12-31'
  AND date_ < '2012-01-01'
  GROUP BY eqid, date_
  ORDER BY eqid, date_
```

**EDIT**

After re-reading your post, it sounds like you want a single row per `eqId`, and for each row, you want a count of days for which `volume`'s value is `0`.

If that's what you want, then this is the query:

(edited to make sure that even when none of the days have a volume of zero, you still get a row with a count of zero)

```
SELECT eqId,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(volume, 0) = 0 THEN 'X' END) AS DayCntWhereVolumeIsZero
  FROM [CRC].[dbo].[eqPrice]
  WHERE date_ > '2007-12-31'
  AND date_ < '2012-01-01'
  GROUP BY eqid
  ORDER BY eqid
```

Comment: Thanks. . .that last suggestion did the trick.  Thanks soooo much for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your are removing the `NULL`s before the count.  Remember `count(<colname>)` counts the number of non-NULL values.  Just do:

```
  count(volume) as hasvol
```

or

```
 coalesce(sum(volume), 0) as hasvol
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, first off Thanks, I tried count(volume) as hasvol but I still have 1 "hasvol" variable for each given day rather than I count of the total number of days where there was either a volume or a zero volume (i would take either)